# (mongodb) How to find null values inside embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I want to  search for this part:

```
"UrunAdi" : {
                "value" : "Büyük Anne 23 cm Vinil El Kuklası",
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
                }
            },
```

urunadı means product name.

So if productname value is null or empty, i want to see as output.

I tried a few, all give wrong syntax errors.

I tried this to match ( then  i would do for null if this worked)

```
db.products.find({fields:{$elemMatch:       "UrunAdi" : {
            "value" : "Vinil El Kuklası (23 cm Tilki)",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.410Z")
            }}}})
```

products is collection inside db product.

or ths failed

```
db.products.find({fields:{$elemMatch:      "UrunAdi" : {
           $elemMatch:   "value" : "Vinil El Kuklası (23 cm Tilki)",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.410Z")
            }}}})
```

This is long version of code. I get this by writing

first

```
use product
```

then

```
db.products.find().pretty()







{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a21569c01432434b6f302b"),
    "_class" : "net..product.domain.Product",
    "status" : "NEW",
    "isValid" : false,
    "isMatched" : true,
    "isAnalyzed" : true,
    "hasValidImage" : true,
    "preMatchedSku" : "HBV000000DED8",
    "merchantSku" : "VRDYW-7320-BA",
    "merchant" : "46dc04b1-a39f-40fb-9697-d4b06f837952",
    "fields" : {
        "YasAraligi" : {
            "value" : "3 yaş üzeri",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "MERCHANT",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-03T16:01:45.720Z")
            }
        },
        "renk_varyant_property" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "MERCHANT",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        "UrunAciklamasi" : {
            "value" : "Çocuklarınıza \"evvel zaman içinde kalbur saman içinde\" ile başlayan hikayeler anlatmak yada onların daha eğlenceli vakit geçirmesini sağlamak için tam aradığınız oyuncak.<div><br></div><div>23 cm vinil el kuklası ile çocuklarınıza bir şeyleri paylaşabilme, beden dilini ve sesini kullanabilme özelliklerini kazandırabilirsiniz. Gerektiğinde kutusunda muhafaza edebilirsiniz.</div><br>Ürün Grubu : El Kuklası<br>Cinsiyet : Kız çocuk<br>Yaş Grubu : 3 yaş üzeri<br>Materyal : Vinil, Keçe<br>Ürün Ölçüsü : 23 cm ölçülerinde<br>Tema : Masal kahramanları<br>",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "hbSku" : {
            "value" : "HBV000000DED8",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "secenek-6_varyant_property" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "MERCHANT",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        "TaxVatRate" : {
            "value" : "18",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Image5" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Image4" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Image3" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Image2" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Kur" : {
            "value" : "TL",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Image1" : {
            "value" : "http://www.puzmo.com.tr/panel/UrunResimleri/puzmo/buyuk-anne-23-cm-vinil-el-kuklasi-80.jpg",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "tipi_varyant_property" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "MERCHANT",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        "VaryantID" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "yas_varyant_property" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "MERCHANT",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        "UrunAdi" : {
            "value" : "Büyük Anne 23 cm Vinil El Kuklası",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "StokAdedi" : {
            "value" : "1",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Cinsiyet" : {
            "value" : "Kız",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "MERCHANT",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-03T16:01:45.720Z")
            }
        },
        "Barcode" : {
            "value" : "2454750265123",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Kg" : {
            "value" : "1",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "olcu_varyant_property" : {
            "value" : "",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "MERCHANT",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }
        },
        "GarantiSuresi" : {
            "value" : "0",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        },
        "Marka" : {
            "value" : "Vardem",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
            }
        }
    },
    "listingStatus" : "FAILED",
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2016-08-03T16:01:00Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-03T16:01:45.811Z"),
    "createdBy" : "user-0",
    "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-19T07:16:16.464Z"),
    "modifiedBy" : "root",
    "type" : DBRef("productTypes", ObjectId("575fd99236623f70c95924c2")),
    "tasks" : [ ]
}
```

I merged 2 answers and this worked
`produp:PRIMARY> db.products.find({"fields.UrunAdi.value":""}).count()
129855`
but it is giving for all products. but i want for each merchant. in sql, we can use distinct for that. `db.products.distinct(  "merchant" )` is true for this but how can i combine those two queries?

Comment: The title is a little bit misleading. What you looking for is not related to array but a field in embedded document "fields". Because as type "fields" is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
db.products.find({$or:[
  {'fields.UrunAdi':{}, 
  {'fields.UrunAdi':{$exists:fasle},
  {'fields.UrunAdi':null}
]})
```

The above query will return the records where `fields.UrunAdi` value is null or `fields.UrunAdi` does not exists or is an empty object.

EDIT:-

Use aggregate like below:

```
db.products.aggregate([{$group: { _id:$merchant}},
  {$match:{
    $or:[
     {'fields.UrunAdi':{}, 
     {'fields.UrunAdi':{$exists:fasle},
     {'fields.UrunAdi':null}]
}}])
```

Refer [doc-aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for more info.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I merged your answers and this worked
`produp:PRIMARY> db.products.find({"fields.UrunAdi.value":""}).count()
129855`
but it is giving for all products. but i want for each merchant. in sql, we can use distinct for that. `db.products.distinct(  "merchant" )` is true for this but how can i combine those two queries?

Comment: I meant i want distinct merhancts, each one is only one time.

Comment: @mark I am not clear about, what exactly you want to achieve. My answer is based on your question and requirement.

Comment: each merchant has a lot of products. there are 1000 merchants but 129855 products. i want to get 1000 merchants not 129855 oroducts. So i need distinct mercants for this. like `db.products.distinct("mechant").find({"fields.UrunAdi.value":""})`

Answer (score 2):

Your `fields` field is not an array but it just contains some documents. 
If you want to find all documents that match this:

```
"UrunAdi" : {
                "value" : "Büyük Anne 23 cm Vinil El Kuklası",
                "detail" : {
                    "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                    "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")
                }
            }
```

you have to use something like this:

```
db.products.find({"fields.UrunAdi.value":"Büyük Anne 23 cm Vinil El Kuklası",
                  "fields.UrunAdi.detail.revisedBy":"CTA",
                  "fields.UrunAdi.detail.revisionDate":
                          {"$date": "2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z"}
})
```

If you get some error extracting your date you can try this too:

```
 db.products.find({"fields.UrunAdi.value":"Büyük Anne 23 cm Vinil El Kuklası",
                   "fields.UrunAdi.detail.revisedBy":"CTA",
                   "fields.UrunAdi.detail.revisionDate":
                           {"$date": {"$gte": new Date("2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z")}
    })
```

Comment: `So if productname value is null or empty, i want to see as output.` I think this is the question. So from your answer, it will return the document which has the specific values, not the empty or the null one.

Comment: Surely this answer is not clear. However there's this sentence too: `I tried this to match ( then i would do for null if this worked)`

Comment: I merged your answers and this worked
`produp:PRIMARY> db.products.find({"fields.UrunAdi.value":""}).count()
129855`
but it is giving for all products. but i want for each merchant. in sql, we can use distinct for that. `db.products.distinct(  "merchant" )` is true for this but how can i combine those two queries? i want mercjants, each one is only one time

Comment: Try:
`db.products.aggregate([
                                        {$group: { _id:$merchant}}, 
                                        {$match: {$and: [ 
{"fields.UrunAdi.value":"Büyük Anne 23 cm Vinil El Kuklası"},
{"fields.UrunAdi.detail.revisedBy":"CTA"},
{"fields.UrunAdi.detail.revisionDate": {"$date": "2016-08-18T08:04:52.448Z"}}]}}]);`

For more info you have to take a look here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/